# lightning-progress-indicator how can I use it for a Case record page in a Community?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to follow this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_example) and apply it to the Case object. I would like to evaluate the Case Status in a Switch statement to set "currentStep" value.

HTML

```
<template>
 <lightning-progress-indicator record-id={recordId} current-step={currentStep} type="path" has-error="true" variant="base">
    <lightning-progress-step label="New" value="1"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Paperwork In Review" value="2"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Change Pending" value="3"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Paperwork Approved" value="4"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Inspection Approved" value="5"></lightning-progress-step>
    <lightning-progress-step label="Project Approved" value="6"></lightning-progress-step>
</lightning-progress-indicator>
```

JavaScript

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = [
    'Case.Status'
];

export default class ProgressIndicator extends LightningElement {

    @track currentStep;
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    case;

    get status() {
        return this.case.data.fields.Status.value;
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        switch (this.FIELDS.case.status) {
            case "New":
                this.currentStep = "1";
                break
            case "Paperwork In Review":
                this.currentStep = "2";
                break
            case "Change Pending":
                this.currentStep = "3";
                break
            case "Paperwork Approved":
                this.currentStep = "4";
                break
            case "Inspection Approved":
                this.currentStep = "5";
                break
            case "Project Approved":
                this.currentStep = "6";
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Meta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

*Updated JavaScript

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = [
    'Case.Status'
];

export default class ProgressIndicator extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    case;

    get status() {
        return this.case.data.fields.Status.value;
    }

    get currentStatus(){
        let tempCurrentStatus
        if(this.case.data) {
            switch (this.case.data.fields.Status.value) {
                case "New":
                    tempCurrentStatus = "1";
                    break
                case "Paperwork In Review":
                    tempCurrentStatus = "2";
                    break
                case "Change Pending":
                    tempCurrentStatus = "3";
                    break
                case "Paperwork Approved":
                    tempCurrentStatus = "4";
                    break
                case "Inspection Approved":
                    tempCurrentStatus = "5";
                    break
                case "Project Approved":
                    tempCurrentStatus = "6";
                    break
            }
        }
        return tempCurrentStatus;
    }
}
```

Updated HTML

```
<template>
     <lightning-progress-indicator record-id={recordId} current-step={currentStatus} type="path" has-error="true" variant="base">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to write the logic in renderedCallback, instead the logic should be in one of the method which you should get invoked whenever the component is rendered.

You need to replace the method renderedCallback with below

```
get currentStatus(){
        let tempCurrentStatus
        switch (this.FIELDS.case.status) {
            case "New":
                tempCurrentStatus = "1";
                break
            case "Paperwork In Review":
                tempCurrentStatus = "2";
                break
            case "Change Pending":
                tempCurrentStatus = "3";
                break
            case "Paperwork Approved":
                tempCurrentStatus = "4";
                break
            case "Inspection Approved":
                tempCurrentStatus = "5";
                break
            case "Project Approved":
                tempCurrentStatus = "6";
                break
        }
   return tempCurrentStatus;
}
```

And remove the variable currentStatus.

Comment: Kiran "And remove the variable currentStatus": are you referring to: @track currentStep;?

Comment: yes that is correct. if you have getter then you would not need that and that is always a calculated value so I would not consider storing it.

Comment: Kiran, how do I set my currentStep attribute on my markup? current-step={tempCurrentStatus} ?

Comment: no change would be needed in markup it should stay as it is which is current-step = {currentStep}

Comment: Kiran - I am a little confused, if I remove the @track currentStep variable, how do we pass the value of tempCurrentStatus to the current-step attribute?

Comment: tempCurrentStatus variable is just the local variable.  current-step = {currentStep} by this statement LWC will make sure to call "get currentStatus(){" the getter.

Comment: there is not need to do anything with tempCurrentStatus. Consider currentStep is a calculated field based on Status which does not need to be stored and it should be calculated all the time. Also as SFDC pointed out, you might want to check if this.FIELDS.case.status this should be this.FIELDS.case.Status. Note the Status field.

Comment: @Tom you would also need to replace "this.FIELDS.case.status" with "this.case.data.fields.Status.value" and place a null check before switch for (this.case.data!=null)

Comment: @User6670 are you referring to the switch statement like this: switch (this.case.data.fields.Status.value)

Comment: @Tom yes also a null check for "this.case.data" before switch

Comment: @User6670 can you please review my updated question and confirm the changes? After deployment, unfortunately the progress indicator is still not dynamic on the Community record detail page.

Comment: @Tom you replaced "currentStep" with "currentStatus" in HTML right?

Comment: @User6670 No, but I have replaced it now. current-step={currentStatus}. That was one of the things I was confused about from the above discussion. Now it is successful. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Field names are case sensitive. Use the getFieldValue method instead:

```
import CASESTATUSFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Status';
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

...

```
get status() {
  return getFieldValue(this.case.data, CASESTATUSFIELD);
}
```

---

Instead of a switch, you can use a simple array:

```
this.currentStep = ''+[
  "",
  "New",
  "Paperwork In Review",
  "Change Pending",
  "Paperwork Approved",
  "Inspection Approved",
  "Project Approved",
].indexOf(getFieldValue(this.case, CASESTATUSFFIELD));
```

This shouldn't be in the renderedCallback, as that causes an infinite loop. Instead, you should be able to simply:

```
get currentStep() {
  return ""+[
  "",
  "New",
  "Paperwork In Review",
  "Change Pending",
  "Paperwork Approved",
  "Inspection Approved",
  "Project Approved",
  ].indexOf(getFieldValue(this.case, CASESTATUSFFIELD));
}
```